# Which pronoun best completes the sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, pronouns

Which pronoun best completes the sentence? Every woman received ***_*___** prize. Is it her or their? Please explain

Comment: Her. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 0):

For the sentences:

> Every day is Christmas.
>
> Every door was open.
>
> Every screw is loose.
>
> Every woman is accounted for.

You have a singular subject.

I would never say

> Every day are Christmas.
>
> Every door were open.
>
> Ever screw are loose.
>
> Every woman are accounted for.

I think in your case, you also have a singular subject in

> Every woman took her seat.

The fact that the verb *took* is the same for a singular or plural subject may be part of the confusion. It clarifies itself when you use a more common verb, like *to be* (is/are, was/were), which still retains its irregular forms.